# Integrating and validating invisible recaptcha

Tags: javascript, php, html, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I want to add recaptcha to a form, I registered for it and got the keys.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Then I added this code to the page:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=My_Website_Key'></script>
```

Next I added this Javascript/Jquery code:

```
//When page is loaded.
$(document).ready(function() { 

    grecaptcha.ready(function() {

        grecaptcha.execute('The Website Key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {});

    }); //Recaptcha ready

}); //Page is loaded
```

Finally I'm trying to verify, But there is no hidden element with a value to use or anything to send to the backend to check.

So how to check from the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

You can link it to the submit button and link it to inputs fields